# How do I limit what classes can change the value of a field in another non related class

Tags: c#

As a part of a video game, I need to store player profiles.

If I have a `Player` class like this:

```
public class Player
{
    public string username { get; private set; }
    public int numberOfWins { get; private set; }

    public void AddWin()
    {
        numberOfWins++;
    }
}
```

and a `Game` class like this:

```
public class Game
{
    Player playerOne;
    Player playerTwo;

    int playerOneScore;
    int playerTwoScore;

    public void HandleGameEnd()
    {
        if (playerOneScore > playerTwoScore)
        {
            playerOne.AddWin();
        }

        else
        {
            playerTwo.AddWin();
        }
    }
}
```

How will I have to change my code to make sure that the only thing that use `AddWin()` is `HandleGameEnd()`?

Comment: There really isn't a way to do that.  But, honestly, you shouldn't *need* to do that.  You control the code, you can control what does or does not call public methods on your objects.

Comment: Can you not just make it a private method of game, and rearrange your class structure?

Comment: @David That is true, but I was just curious as to whether there's a way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create an interface e.g.

```
interface ICanAddWin
{
    void AddWin();
}
```

and then implement it in your Player explicitely:

```
class Player : ICanAddWin
{
    void ICanAddWin.AddWin() { ... }
}
```

The `Game` should use `ICanAddWin` objects, not `Player` (you can add more methods if required). Other classes don't know about `AddWin` method unless they cast `Player` to internal interface `ICanAddWin` which requires them to be in the same assembly and to add `using` for that interface namespace (actually in better design each "client" should see only some specific interface that it requires, not `Player` class; casting is a bad practice).

It would be even better to move the `AddWin` method to a separate class (may be private nested in `Player` to have an access to its private fields) that implements `ICanAddWin`. This way when you pass a `Player` somewhere you are absolutely sure that it can't be casted to `ICanAddWin`.

For better understanding I suggest you to learn more OOP and SOLID (especially interface segregation and dependency inversion parts).

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that approach you suggest is not best from design point of view but you can achieve that using:

```
StackFrame frame = new StackFrame(1);
var method = frame.GetMethod();
var type = method.DeclaringType; //caller's type
var name = method.Name; //method name
```